# InMemory DB doesn't return nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set }
    public List<Worker> Subordinates { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using an InMemory Database. The problem is that when I want to get the workers it returns null on the Subordinates property. However, when I debug it to see if the list of subordinates is loading it behaves as expected:

[image]

(It says count=2 but if I just run it without debugging it returns null for that property)

EDIT:
this is the query:

```
    public Worker GetById(string id)
    {
        return _workerContext.Workers.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }
```

EDIT:
in-memory db:

```
        services.AddDbContext<WorkerContext>((options =>
        {
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("WorkerDB");
        }));
```

Comment: Can you show us the query ?

Comment: What does "without debugging it and clicking on the properties" mean? How are you clicking on the properties to see values if you're not debugging? Do you mean in your UI? It sounds like the problem is maybe in your UI binding.

Comment: `an InMemory Database.` what in-memory DB? EF Core's in-memory provider is essentially a wrapper over List<T> . This means it can hold *far more complex data* than a database can, but won't support the same functionality as a database.

Comment: It looks like you tried to load hierarchical, not nested, data. But it looks like the `Workers` collection of each entity didn't have any data to begin with. How did you *insert* the data into the `Subordinates` property in each case? The in-memory provider won't try to rebuild the hierarchy the way the Relational provider does - it doesn't need to. One object can contain whatever it wants, unlike a database table that can only contain atomic values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try two different ways. The first way is to make the `List<Subordinates>` a virtual property (this will enable lazy loading).

```
public virtual List<Worker> Subordinates { get; set; }
```

The second way would be to explicitly include the `List<Subordinates>`.

```
return _workerContext.Workers.Include(w => w.Subordinates).SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

Now I am not sure that this will fix your issue, but it is something you can try. I am not very familiar with `InMemory Databases`

Comment: I tried the second way and it does solve the problem. However, it doesn't retrieve the subordinates of the subordinates. I mean, if John Doe has two subordinates and those two have two more each, it only retrieves John's two subordinates.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend trying the first way. That should make it load all of them. In theory at least.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy here is some documentation on lazy loading